# Log4Net not generating log file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log4net

I have `ASP.Net WebAPI` project & using `Log4Net` API.

```
 protected void LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        var msgParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Message", ex.Message },
                    { "StackTrace", ex.StackTrace },
                };

        _logger.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgParams));
    }
```

XML Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <log4net>
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

    <file value="App.log" />

    <appendToFile value="true" />

    <maximumFileSize value="50KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

    <encoding value="utf-8" />

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>

</appender>

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</root>
```

But when any exception occurs & above LogException() gets hit, ***neither I am getting any exception nor I see any App.Log file*** in my directory.

What I am missing here?
Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: If you use a runtime tracing tool like debugbiew you may  find that the apppool account doesn't have permission to create the file. You should configure logging to another location outside the application root.

Comment: @tomredfern, I am running as Adminstrator

Comment: Just to confirm you are configuring log4net at runtime using XmlConfigurator or an assembly attribute?

Comment: @stuartd, as assembly attribute

Comment: try add the line [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)] before namespace declaration

Comment: Try to write your log in the APP_DATA folder (Ie /APP_DATA/App.log)

Comment: Does `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured` return true?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the location:

```
<file value="App.log" />
```

This will log relative to your webserver directory, not the location of you code/executable. Set the full path to test this, the log location has to be writable for the user that runs your application.

Comment: I checked. nothing such

Comment: It should be writable for the IIS process that runs the request.